# How do I sequence Cucumber Tags in Runner Class

Tags: tags, cucumber, runner

I am using these tags in my runner.java to run scenarios in my Cucumber/Java/Selenium Framework
tags="@order01, @location01, @location02, @location03, @location04",

Even order01 is the 1st scenario in the list of tags, it runs last after all the location scenarios are run. How do I make order01 to run 1st?

I have tried putting order01 at the end of the list, thinking it is reading from right of left which still makes order01 to run last.

Here is my complete runner.java

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin={"html:target/cucumber","json:target/report.json"},
    features = "src/test/resources/features",
    glue="steps",
    tags="@order01, @location01, @location02, @location03, @location04",
    dryRun =false

)

public class Runner {

}
```

I was expecting that order01 scenario would run first. however, it runs last in this case.

Comment: why do you want to run the @order01 tag at first? is there any dependency?

Comment: Your scenarios should be independent; meaning they should pass or fail for their own reason, and not depend on other scenarios having run first. See also the [docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/community/faq/#how-do-i-call-other-steps-or-scenarios)

Comment: There is no dependency. It is just the logical progression of the test scenarios.  Any way, I now understand that since scenarios should be independent, they can be placed in any order.  Thanks for your answers!